# should you take question mark as a separate word in bigram language modelling when finding probability?

Tags: natural-language-processing

the corpus

<s>what is the shape ?</s> 
 <s>what is the colour ?</s> 
 <s>what colour is it ?</s> 
 <s>it is what ?</s> 
 <s>is it red ?</s> 
 <s>what is it ?</s> 
 <s>what shape is it ?</s> 
 <s>it is red</s> 
 <s>it is green</s> 
 <s>the colour is red</s> 
 <s>the shape is square</s> 
 <s>red is the colour</s> 
 <s>square is the shape</s>

(1) What is the probability of the following sentences: (4 points)

a.   what colour is red ?

Comment: It's up to you – you're defining the model.

Comment: (With a blank before a punctuation mark regularly going without, I'm not strictly against it. (*word*:: consecutive non-blanks))